# Align Circle Text

Tags: html, css, geometry

For some reason, my CSS file will not align my circle on the page.

This is my html object for a circle:

```
<div class="circle-text">Upload your photo here</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.circle-text {
display: table-cell;
height: 400px; /*change this and the width
for the size of your initial circle*/
width: 400px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
align
border-radius: 50%;
/*make it pretty*/
background: #000;
padding-top:;
color: #fff;
font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;
```

}

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say your CSS won't align your circle on the page? Align it with what, exactly?

Comment: The screenshot of the problem would be helpful.Please share that.

Comment: It's perfect text already center of div and please remove `align` below of  `vertical-align: middle;` property.  It is extra part of css.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
.circle-text{
    margin: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it works

```css
.circle-text {
height: 400px; /*change this and the width
for the size of your initial circle*/
width: 400px;
line-height: 400px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 100%;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,0);
/*make it pretty*/
background: #000;
color: #fff;
font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;}
.circle-text .txt{
  line-height: 400px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-text"><div class="txt">

Upload your photo here</div></div>
```